# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property '__guards__' of undefined in NestJs

Tags: typescript, authentication, nestjs, passport.js

I'm working on implementing a simple authentication in a Nest project.

When I add

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
```

to my controller I have the following Error :

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property '__guards__' of undefined
 at /home/cedric/Bureau/programmation/project_bank/project/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:147:152
```

I followed all the Nest official documentation to do this.

My controller is

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    return req.body.username;
  }
```

and my auth.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

Comment: can you share the output of `npx nest info`

Comment: Of course ! [System Information]
OS Version     : Linux 5.15
NodeJS Version : v16.0.0
NPM Version    : 7.10.0 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 9.1.9 

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 9.2.1
schematics version       : 9.0.4
passport version         : 9.0.3
swagger version          : 6.1.4
testing version          : 9.3.7
common version           : 9.2.1
core version             : 9.3.7
cli version              : 9.1.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say this is a dependency version mismatch issue.

You need to ensure that `@nestjs/platform-express`, `@nestjs/core` and  `@nestjs/common` are in the same version (I believe that only the minor slice matters).

Comment: Perfect!! I instanciated a new project in which I copied my code. This project is workind. The only differences between the two project was the platform-express version : 9.2.1 to 9.3.8! I just needed to update.

Answer (score 0):

It really was a dependency version mismatch.

I followed this procedure to update my project :

1. Install ncu from the npm-check-updates library:

```
sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

2. Run ncu in the project folder :

```
ncu
```

3. Update your dependencies:

```
ncu -u
```

4. Finally, install the updates

```
npm install
```