# NestJS updates break service

Tags: dependencies, nestjs

I have updated my dependencies in my Nest microservices and now I receive the following error at start:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '**guards**')".
This is the diff in package.json:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdQfI.png)

Any idea how to fix this? Or should I just rollback to the versions that were working previously.
This is the npm audit report I got:

## npm audit report

@nestjs/core  <9.0.5
Severity: moderate
@nestjs/core vulnerable to Information Exposure via StreamableFile pipe - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4jpv-8r57-pv7j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @nestjs/core@9.3.12, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/@nestjs/core

class-validator  <0.14.0
Severity: critical
SQL Injection and Cross-site Scripting in class-validator - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fj58-h2fr-3pp2
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install class-validator@0.14.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/class-validator
@nestjs/mapped-types  <=1.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of class-validator
node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types
@nestjs/swagger  4.5.2 - 6.1.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @nestjs/mapped-types
node_modules/@nestjs/swagger

webpack  5.0.0 - 5.75.0
Severity: high
Cross-realm object access in Webpack 5 - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hc6q-2mpp-qw7j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @nestjs/cli@9.3.0, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/webpack
@nestjs/cli  7.5.1-next.1 || 7.5.2-next.2 - 9.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
node_modules/@nestjs/cli

6 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 2 high, 3 critical)

(Any input, articles, docs, is appreciated; didn't find anything online so far)

I tried scanning the internet for a solution, but nothing so far. Rolling back the updates does the trick, but I would be interested in a way to keep the latest versions.

Comment: The `npm audit` report is for scanning for vulnerabilities and security issues, so it's irrelevant in this case.

The answer is probably that you upgraded 1 nestjs dependency, but they are supposed to be kept in sync (your `core`, `common` and `platform-express` subpackages are different versions). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474899/error-exceptionhandler-cannot-read-property-guards-of-undefined-in-nestj

Comment: did you found any solution for webpack?

Answer (score 0):

This is that one thing in programming that makes you want to bang your head on the wall multiple times.
All you can do is check the updates for the dependencies creating problems, then update them if an update is available. If they do not exist yet, all you can do is rollback your changes. That is why usually it is not recommended to rush with the updates until stable versions are released, etc.